# UITableview didselecetrowatindex performsegue after URL Response

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableview in a view controller.  When a row is clicked everything is fine.  I fire off a NSURLConnection request to get information back.  However this is where my problem starts.  If I use perfromsegue then the segue occurs before the response is returned.  If I use instantiateviewcontroller I get an error "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present a nil modal view controller on target .'"  My question really is how can I get to the new view controller after I have received my response?

Here is the end of the block of code where I am calling the segue.

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]     completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
{
    NSLog(@"THIS IS THE NEW RESPONSE %@",response);
    messageBody= [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"THIS IS responseData = %@", messageBody);
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ViewMessage" sender:nil];
}];
```

I would upload a picture of the storyboard but I don't have enough reputation points to do that.

Comment: I have found that my storyboard is null when I am trying to perfrom the segue or instantiate the new view.  That is causing my problem.  Now I just need to know how to make sure my storyboard is not null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You connect the segue from the controller, and call `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` in the `connectionDidFinishLoading:` delegate method.

Comment: I did this an I still received the error.  However this lead me to find out that my storyboard is null.  I tried to set it using self.storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil]; but this gave me an error "assignment to read only property".  If I can just set the storyboard correctly I think i will be in business.  Thanks for you help.

Comment: @user3728381, I assume that the controller you have the table view in is in the same storyboard as the one you're segueing to. In that case, you can get the storyboard with self.storyboard.

Comment: I tried already using the: self.storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil]; and it did not work.  My project has a navigation controller at the begining, a login screen, and then a view controller with the tableview inside it.  So on my 2nd screen is where I am encountering the problem.

Comment: Why are you even trying to access the storyboard? If you have a segue set up, then you don't need to access the storyboard at a all. You don't need to instantiate the new view controller, the segue does that for you.

Comment: I have tried both ways figuring that atleast one would work.  It doesn't...I am at a loss for what is going on here.  I can segue to different view controllers from this view controller as well and that is what is causing me the most greif.

Comment: @user3728381, you should post the code you're using now, and describe what you have set up in the storyboard. It's hard to offer any solution without seeing your code.

Comment: give me a moment and I will do that

Comment: @user3728381, Do you have a segue called "ViewMessage" connected from the controller that has the code you posted? Are you still getting the same error message you have in your question?

Comment: Yes my segue is "ViewMessage".  the problem is that the receiver does not have a segue "ViewMessage".  I have found that because the storyboard is null that it won't work.  That is why it isn't working but I am not sure how to get the storyboard set.  It was working before and now it is not.

Comment: @user3728381, but isn't the controller that has the code you posted in the same storyboard? If so, I don't see how the storyboard can be null, or you wouldn't see anything when the app launched. You shouldn't have to "set" the storyboard.

Comment: I agree.  This is what makes it so frustrating.  I put another button on the view to perform the same action on a button press and it worked so now I have narrowed it down to the method that I am calling it in.

Comment: I can't see how that can be -- seems like your storyboard is either null or it's not; it shouldn't matter what method needs to access something there. Anyway, if you want me to take a look at it, I will , if you can upload the project somewhere, or email it to me.

Comment: That would be great if you can have a look at it.  Where would you like me to send it?

Comment: Zip up the project folder (not just the .xcodeproj file), and send it to me at rdelmar@comcast.net

Comment: just sent it to you.  Thanks for all your help.  This one has really stumped me.